# Use Joomla article title as a variable inside a paragraph

Tags: articles

I'm looking to set up a bunch of pages that have the same paragraph except one bit of text that will be the same as whatever the article's title is. Is there a way to pull in the article's title as a variable in Joomla?

Something like:

`<p>Welcome to the ${ArticleTitle} Page!</p>`

Comment: Welcome to JSE, aglasier.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Regular Labs plugin Article Anywhere which is available for both J!3 and J!4 You *might* need the Pro version (euro39)

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour] and perhaps tell us about yourself by editing you profile.